# Salvar estado dos fragments que esta em um viewPager

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Sempre que o dispositivo é rotacionado estou perdendo o conteúdo dos fragments que estão em três tabs, já fiz uso do onSaveInstanceState em Activity mais agora estou levando um banho porque de minha Activity principal estou chamando um Mainfragement este por sua vez recupera os três objetos

```
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
```

e infla a view que tem três Fragments, o A, B e C, inicialmente eu tentei fazer a recuperação em cada fragment mais não é isto pois continuo perdendo os dados de cada view então com certeza tenho que atuar no MainFragment

Estou tentando alterar o adaptador para solucionar o problema, procurando ainda referencias na documentação se alguém puder dar uma força

Aqui esta o meu adaptador

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   private Fragment[] currentFragment ;
   private String[] mTabTiles;
   private Context mContext;

   public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, String[] tabTiles) {
      super(fm);
      this.mTabTiles = tabTiles;
      this.mContext = context;
      this.currentFragment = new Fragment[this.mTabTiles.length];
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       Fragment frag = null;

       if (position==0){
          frag = new FragmentA();
        } else if(position==1){
          frag = new FragmentB();
        } else if(position==2){
          frag = new FragmentC();
      }


     currentFragment[position] = frag;

     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putInt("position",position);

     frag.setArguments(b);

    return frag;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return this.mTabTiles.length;
   }

   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

       return this.mTabTiles[position] ;
   }
```

}

e o MainFragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

   private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";

   private TabLayout mTabLayout;
   private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
   private ViewPager mViewPager;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

       Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView()");

       mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titulo));

       mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
       // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
       mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
       mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
       mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

       return view;
}


   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

       Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

       //outState.putInt("currentTab", mTabLayout.getCurrentTab());
       outState.putInt("position", mTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
       outState.putInt("currentPage", mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
   }

   @Override
   public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

       Log.i(TAG, "onViewStateRestored");

       if(savedInstanceState!=null) {

           Log.i(TAG, "onViewStateRestored -> Posição: " +    savedInstanceState.getInt("position"));

           mViewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("position"));

           Log.i(TAG, "onViewStateRestored -> Posição: " + savedInstanceState.getInt("position") + " -> mViewPager.setCurrentItem()");

         mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("position"));

           Log.i(TAG, "onViewStateRestored -> Posição: " + savedInstanceState.getInt("position") + " -> mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem()");

       }
   }
```

o que eu consegui pesquisar eu atualizei o método onSaveInstanceState e criei criei o onViewStateRestored na classe MainFragment que já atualizei no código acima, embora esta alteração não tenha dado o resultado esperado, eu estou chamando o Adapter da ViewPage com a posição da Tab e observo no logcat os eventos quando eu rotaciono o dispositivo

```
// Salvando os estados
I/MainFragment: onSaveInstanceState
I/FragmentA: onSaveInstanceState()
I/FragmentB: onSaveInstanceState()


I/MainFragment: onCreateView()
// Nova instancia do adaptador
I/SectionsPagerAdapter: SectionsPagerAdapter()
// Aqui vejo que foi obtida a posição 0 da Tab ou seja a primeira Tab 
I/MainFragment: onViewStateRestored
I/MainFragment: onViewStateRestored -> Posição: 0
I/MainFragment: onViewStateRestored -> Posição: 0 ->     mViewPager.setCurrentItem()
I/SectionsPagerAdapter: getItem( 0)
I/MainFragment: onViewStateRestored -> Posição: 0 ->    mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem()
I/FragmentA: onCreateView()
I/FragmentA: onActivityCreated()

I/MainFragment: onCreateView()
I/SectionsPagerAdapter: SectionsPagerAdapter()
I/MainFragment: onViewStateRestored
```

Comment: Seja mais explicito em relação a quais valores pretende guardar.

Comment: Olá Ramaral, então eu preciso quando rotacionar o dispositivo as informações que tenho nas Tabs continuem só isto. Quando isto ocorre eu tenho que selecionar Tab por Tab uma a uma para que o seu conteúdo apareça.

Comment: Não entendi. Se ao seleccionar a tab o conteúdo aparece é porque ele foi guardado.

Comment: Quando eu seleciono a Tab manualmente sim claro aparece isto porque o Adaptador ( SectionsPagerAdapter ) é chamado e executa o getItem(). O que eu quero e acredito que seja este comportamento de todo app é quando eu acesso uma Atividade e rotaciono o dispositivo o Android reconstroi a Tela, então usando os métodos para guardar eu posso restaurar a tela e é este o meu intento, vou atualizar o que consegui pesquisando estes dias.

Comment: Fiz uma atualização da classe MainFragment, atualizei também minha pergunta com o log dos eventos, embora eu esteja pesquisando o TabLayout e procurando salvar a posição getSelectedTabPosition() esperava muito que o viewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(posicao)) pudesse resolver o problema e restaurar os dados quando eu rotacionasse o dispositivo pois foi o que eu entendi, mais estou na pesquisa

Comment: Quando diz que "não aparece" quando roda o dispositivo, quer dizer que a tela fica em branco? Por que tem o TabLayout no layout de um fragment e não no da activity?

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem da tela rotacionada acredito que agora dê para exemplificar o que esta ocorrendo, na orientação retrato todas as tabs tinham conteúdo qdo eu rotaciono eles desaparecem mesmo eu salvando e recuperando o estado.

Comment: Isso não devia acontecer. As views são recuperadas automaticamente pelo sistema. O único facto estranho(nunca vi fazer assim) é o TabLayout  estar no layout de um fragment e não no da activity, poderá ser essa a razão desse comportamento anómalo.

Comment: ramaral, o motivo de estar em um fragment é o projeto foi criado com o Navigation Drawer, a atividade principal continha ao Tabs e o ViewPager, só que eu coloquei outras atividades no menu do Drawer e chamando estas eu perdia o Menu Drawer, ficou feio então transformei tudo em fragments e o que estava na activity principal os tabs eu passei para um fragmentMain, no inicio do projeto eu não testei a rotação do dispositivo mais vou fazer isto voltando o código.

Comment: Crie uma activity com o Drawer, depois herde as outras activities dessa.

Comment: Fiz um teste criei outro projeto, e sem Fragments na atividade principal, os fragments são só para os Tabs, no xml da activity o ViewPage e realmente tudo funcionou como deveria e eu nem precisei salvar estado de nada na activity, nada, ou seja o rolo ocorreu qdo eu "migrei" o Tabs e o ViewPage para um fragment, então ramaral vc esta certo quado disse "Isso não deveria acontecer".

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um outro projeto no qual eu faço uso do tabs com TabLayout, ViewPager chamando de uma activity com esta abordagem o posicionamento do dispositivo não ocasionou nenhum problema na view tudo funcionou corretamente, então conclui que eu ter migrado os objetos tablayout e viewpage para um fragment foi o que ocasionou o comportamento.